# Display JS error message after WordPress update

Tags: wordpress

After updating my WordPress site template, this error message is displayed at the top of the pages and in the template settings section. How can I fix these problems?[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This may be a problem related to the new 5.5 wordpress. There is a new plugin you can activate to fix it. Here is an [article](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/how-to-fix-wordpress-5-5/378452/) fore reference

Comment: That's right- but I want to know how to fix these errors

Comment: Look at the article